# Declare multibyte character array where bytes > 2

Tags: c++, c, character-encoding

How can I declare a multibyte character array in which each is character is represented for 3 or 4 bytes?

I know I can do: `char var[] = "AA";`  which will write to memory `6161` and I can do `wchar var[] = L"AA";` which will do `00610061`. How can I declare a wider character array in C or C++?

Is there any other prefix like the `L` to instruct the compiler to do so?

Comment: Your assumption about `wchar_t` is not entirely correct. Also, look up `char16_t` and `char32_t` string literals.

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal for other character width prefixes for string literals

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both C and C++ offer `char32_t`.  In [C `char32_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte/char32_t) is a typedef of/same type  as [`uint_least32_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer).  In [C++ `char32_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/char32_t) has the same size, signedness, and alignment as [`std::uint_least32_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer), but is a distinct type.

Both of them can be used like

```
char32_t string[] = U"some text";
```

Comment: @user1618465 At least 32

Comment: Awesome! Just out of curiosity. Is there away to use 64 bits per character?

Comment: @user1618465 There isn't a standard method.  You would have to make your own using a `int64_t` like `int64_t string[] = { 'f', 'o', 'o', '\0' };`

Comment: Thank you Nathan. Just one last thing so the answer can be more complete. How could you convert string to a 1 byte character wide array back? Regards

Comment: @user1618465 That is going to depend on what you want to have happen.  If one of your characters is more than one byte wide what should happen?  you could always cast the array to a `char*` to iterate over it as if it were a regular char array.  You would need to ask a new question for this.

Comment: "In C char32_t is a typedef for uint_least32_t" - This is not guaranteed by the language, nor necessarily correct for typical implementations.

Comment: @Olaf C11 7.27.2 *[...]  and `char32_t` which is an unsigned integer type used for 32-bit characters and is the same type as `uint_least32_t`[...]*

Comment: Hmm, seems you are right about the text. But not the chapter: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.28p2

Comment: @Olaf I was using [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf) which is probably a little older

Comment: @NathanOliver: It is indeed outdated. The version I linked is the final draft which is identical to the standard, except for two macro values (not relevant for normal usage). Btw: it is not clear why OP wants to use wide characters at all and not simply uses UTF-8 (which is the default for most modern compilers and OSs).

Answer (score 1):

You could try this, as long as you don't mind manually typing out each character:

```
int characters[3] = { 'h', 'e', 'y' };
```

You can also use a capital U in front of the string literal to get UTF-32:

```
char32_t characters[] = U"hey";
```

Comment: Don't forget about the null terminator.

Comment: I know I can do that. I was expecting a more "elegant" way to do it.

Comment: @JoshKarns If you treat each element of the array as a "character" then you are still missing a null terminator.  You need to full element in the array that is set to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet when talking multi-byte character arrays is to use UTF8 encoding.  That way all of the standard string library functions will continue to work, and ASCII representations remain the same.